# React Native: require() function for static images is too slow

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, image, mobile

I am using ignite react native boilerplate. I have the following component where i import all my image icons:

```
import { ComponentType } from "react"
import {
  Image,
  ImageStyle,
  Pressable,
  StyleProp,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableOpacityProps,
  View,
  ViewStyle,
} from "react-native"
import Ripple from "react-native-material-ripple"

import clsxm from "../../lib/clsxm"

export type IconTypes = keyof typeof iconRegistry

interface IconProps extends TouchableOpacityProps {
  icon: IconTypes
  color?: string
  size?: number
  className?: string
  containerStyle?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>
  onPress?: TouchableOpacityProps["onPress"]
  preset?: "default" | "ripple" | "opacity" | "image"
}

/**
 * A component to render a registered icon.
 * It is wrapped in a <TouchableOpacity /> if `onPress` is provided, otherwise a <View />.
 *
 * - [Documentation and Examples](https://github.com/infinitered/ignite/blob/master/docs/Components-Icon.md)
 */
export function Icon(props: IconProps) {
  const {
    icon,
    color,
    size,
    className,
    containerStyle: $containerStyleOverride,
    preset = "default",
    style,
    ...WrapperProps
  } = props

  const isPressable = !!WrapperProps.onPress
  const Wrapper: ComponentType<TouchableOpacityProps> = WrapperProps?.onPress
    ? preset === "ripple"
      ? Ripple
      : preset === "opacity"
      ? TouchableOpacity
      : Pressable
    : View

  return (
    <Wrapper
      accessibilityRole={isPressable ? "imagebutton" : undefined}
      {...WrapperProps}
      style={$containerStyleOverride}
      rippleSize={110}
    >
      <Image
        style={[$imageStyle, color && { tintColor: color }, size && { width: size, height: size }]}
        className={clsxm(className)}
        source={iconRegistry[icon]}
      />
    </Wrapper>
  )
}

export const iconRegistry = {
  plus: require("../../../assets/icons/plus.png"),
  box: require("../../../assets/icons/box.png"),
  close: require("../../../assets/icons/close.png"),
  search: require("../../../assets/icons/search.png"),
  back: require("../../../assets/icons/back.png"),
  bell: require("../../../assets/icons/bell_new.png"),
  caretLeft: require("../../../assets/icons/caretLeft.png"),
  caretRight: require("../../../assets/icons/caretRight.png"),
  check: require("../../../assets/icons/check.png"),
  clap: require("../../../assets/icons/clap.png"),
  community: require("../../../assets/icons/community.png"),
  components: require("../../../assets/icons/components.png"),
  debug: require("../../../assets/icons/debug.png"),
  github: require("../../../assets/icons/github.png"),
  heart_new: require("../../../assets/icons/heart_new.png"),
  hidden: require("../../../assets/icons/hidden.png"),
  ladybug: require("../../../assets/icons/ladybug.png"),
  lock: require("../../../assets/icons/lock.png"),
  menu: require("../../../assets/icons/menu_new.png"),
  more: require("../../../assets/icons/more.png"),
  pin: require("../../../assets/icons/pin.png"),
  podcast: require("../../../assets/icons/podcast.png"),
  settings: require("../../../assets/icons/settings.png"),
  slack: require("../../../assets/icons/slack.png"),
  view: require("../../../assets/icons/view.png"),
  x: require("../../../assets/icons/x.png"),
  melon: require("../../../assets/icons/melon.png"),
  chatIcon: require("../../../assets/icons/bottom/chat.png"),
  chatFilledIcon: require("../../../assets/icons/bottom/chat_fill.png"),
  homeIcon: require("../../../assets/icons/bottom/home.png"),
  homeFilledIcon: require("../../../assets/icons/bottom/home_fill.png"),
  locationIcon: require("../../../assets/icons/bottom/location.png"),
  locationFilledIcon: require("../../../assets/icons/bottom/location_fill.png"),
  newspaperIcon: require("../../../assets/icons/bottom/newspaper.png"),
  newspaperFilledIcon: require("../../../assets/icons/bottom/newspaper_fill.png"),
  userIcon: require("../../../assets/icons/bottom/profile.png"),
  userFilledIcon: require("../../../assets/icons/bottom/profile_fill.png"),
  car: require("../../../assets/icons/car.png"),
  house: require("../../../assets/icons/house.png"),
  food: require("../../../assets/icons/food.png"),
  work: require("../../../assets/icons/work.png"),
}

const $imageStyle: ImageStyle = {
  resizeMode: "contain",
}
```

When i open the app it takes longer than remote images to load static ones. I am using react-native-fast-image for remote images. But still I have to wait for som time to see static images. Because this is my first experience with React-native I am not quite sure about what to do?

is it only slow in dev mode or can I do something to make this faster?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a better way to import your image, but when you build your application, the require, will not be slow and appear instant.